# Converting strings to widget names QT 5.6

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic-programming

I am currently working on a Qt C++ program with over 152 QPushButtons. What I would like the program to do is recolor a specific QPushButton when a specific condition is met (I have four colors for four conditions). I have arrays that keep track of each condition for each QPushButton but so far the only thing I have managed to get working is this:

```
ui->locker100->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 150, 255); border-color: rgb(50, 0, 128);");
```

Where locker100 is a specific QPushButton. What I would like to do is concatenate a QString with an array resulting in the QPushButton's name. It would look something like this:

```
bool key[152];
std::fill(key, key + 152, true);
Qstring widgetName = "locker";
int input = 100;

if (key[input] == true)
{
    ui->widgetName + input->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 150, 255); border-color: rgb(50, 0, 128);");
}
```

However concatenating creates errors. Any feedback and specific code would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Put the wigets in a map using the name as the key. Then you can do something like this. mymap [widgername]->....

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to see the code for that. Would you mind explaining your answer in further detail?

Comment: Alternatively,  to minimized your effort: QString styleString = QString("QPushButton#locker%1{background-color: rgb(75, 150, 255); border-color: rgb(50, 0, 128);}").arg(input); this->setStyleSheet(styleString);

Comment: @Devopia This is really close to what im trying to accomplish and is super easy to implement! The only qualm I have with it so far is that it seems to reset all my other styles on the form. Other than that, this concept works like a charm. instead of using an int though I just added two strings together. here is the code: **QString input = "1";
    QString styleString = QString("#locker"+input+"{background-color: rgb(0, 150, 255); border-color: rgb(50, 0, 128);}");
    this->setStyleSheet(styleString);** Thoughts on what im doing to cause all the styles to reset?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that code to do anything "#locker" +input is an incomplete  qualifier.  I am not sure how the stylesheet interprets  that.

Comment: It actually works. I put it into my code and does what I want it to do.I think your right though Pemdas, its incomplete as the code does reset my other styles. If I can get it to stop reseting my styles I will be in good shape. Any ideas how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do, but you can't create identifiers by simply constructing a string that happens to be the name that you assigned the identifier. The result is still a QString and you are trying to call the method setStyleSheet() on a QString, which doesn't exist. This tells me that your understanding identifiers, types and objects in general could use some freshening up.

I believe the following code does what you are looking for though.

```
//Create a map of QPushButtons with a QString key.
QMap<QString, QPushButton*> buttonMap;

//As an example I create and add a QPushButton to the map
QPushButton * input100 = new QPushButton();
buttonMap.insert("input100", input100);

//Construct the key
QString button = "input100";

// In this map  .value(key) returns a QPushButton * so
// we can call what ever public functions a QPushButton
// supports like this:
buttonMap.value(button)->setStyleSheet(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Pemdas. So I copied the code into a new QT widgets application to test it out, making sure that there was a QPushButton called input100 and that the setStyleSheet(...) was filled with the proper values. The result was that the code compiled however the pushbutton didn't change color. But I think your on the right track Pemdas. Penny for your thoughts?

Comment: I think you have re-polish the widget for it pick up property changes.

Answer (score 1):

With the warning that you'll have to use the preprocessor:

`#define GET_BUTTON(id) ui->locker##id`

The better answer:

- You're defining 152 buttons in a header somewhere, e.g. `QPushbutton *locker1;`. Don't do that.
- Use constant values as keys, such as an `enum`, store your data in `QHash<SomeEnum, bool>`, and the buttons in a `QHash<SomeEnum, QPushButton *>`.
- Using constants to access the `bool`s and buttons is more flexible and less breakable. It also leaves out the preprocessor, which is always a good idea.

Comment: Thats not a bad idea for storing data and buttons. I know that QHash has some similarities to QMap. Judging by the code given to me by pemdas though, I think I'm still going to run into the same issue. The code compiles, the program runs, but the pushbutton does not change color. I'm missing something.

Comment: That's a different question. :-/ Sounds like you need to inherit `QPushButton` and reimplement `paintEvent`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could set icons for the state of the button, and have the icon the appropriate color. It wouldn't set the entire background, but it will communicate the button state to the user. Using @Pemdas example: `buttonMap.value(button)->setIcon(iconForSomeState);`.

Comment: hmmm, now there's a thought. I never considered using an image/icon to convey the state of my button. I'll give that a shot. If it works, I'll post a working piece of code and instructions for others like me struggling with this type of issue... that is, unless someone beats me to it lol. The one possible issue I can see cropping up with this approach is that the icon could obscure the button's label. All things considered though, I'd rather tackle a problem like that instead lol. Thanks for the idea!